# Directory of Snapshots

Tags: image, shell, tcsh

I have snapshots (photos) that I load off my camera's memory card, and store in a folder. Sometimes I have videos, and occasionally plain audio too (the camera can record just sound).

Additionally, my wife, and kids have their point-and-shoots too.

I have a workflow where I dump the photos on to a designated folder on a linux samba share, and then run this script which identifies the photos, auto-rotates the portrait picturs, and renames them according to the date and time the picture was taken (rather than a sequential number from the camera).

This way, assuming the various cameras have the correct clock-time set, the different cameras all have photos that are named similar things (and can be sorted alphabetically to get them in chronological order too.

**Notes**:

- the jhead program the script calls will rename/rotate the photos, and the name will become something like: `Img20140217-164850.20.jpg`
- the jhead also identifies that some pictures may have 'raw' partners, for example, my Nikon camera takes a picture called `DSC1234.JPG` and simultaneously the picture `DSC1234.NEF` (the raw photo). The command `jhead -aNEF -ft -autorot -n DSC*.JPG` will identify the JPG photo, strip the .JPG extensions, and, because there is also the `-aNEF` argument, will rename the matching NEF file to the same base-name (`Img*`) as the JPG.... in other words, for the files `DSC1234.JPG` and `DSC1234.JPG`, the jhead program will produce, for example, both `Img20140217-164850.20.jpg` and `Img20140217-164850.20.NEF`
- the script deals with both Canon, and Nikon raw files (`RW2` and `NEF` respectively)

The script is relatively simple, but has a fair amount of repetition. Any suggestions for how to improve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -f

#cd /valuable/picxfer

# Do the .jpg first because the jhead program will write .jpg even for .JPG input.
echo 'Checking DSC*.jpg'
if ( `tcsh -f -c "ls -1 DSC*.jpg >& /dev/null" && echo yes` == "yes" ) then
  jhead -anef -ft -autorot -n DSC*.jpg
else
  echo no Nikon jpg files
endif

echo 'Checking DSC*.JPG'
if ( `tcsh -f -c "ls -1 DSC*.JPG >& /dev/null" && echo yes` == "yes" ) then
  jhead -aNEF -ft -autorot -n DSC*.JPG
else
  echo no Nikon JPG files
endif


echo 'Checking *.jpg'
if ( `tcsh -f -c "ls -1 p*.jpg >& /dev/null" && echo yes` == "yes" ) then
  jhead -arw2 -ft -autorot -n p*.jpg
else
  echo no Canon jpg files
endif

echo 'Checking *.JPG'
if ( `tcsh -f -c "ls -1 P*.JPG >& /dev/null" && echo yes` == "yes" ) then
  jhead -aRW2 -ft -autorot -n P*.JPG
else
  echo no Canon JPG files
endif


echo Setting permissions
chmod ugo=r Img*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` conditions can be simplified. Instead of this:

```
if ( `tcsh -f -c "ls -1 DSC*.jpg >& /dev/null" && echo yes` == "yes" ) then
```

You could write like this:

```
if ( `ls DSC*.jpg >& /dev/null && echo x` != "" ) then
```

That is:

- you don't need to spawn a `tcsh` sub-shell
- you don't need the `-1` for `ls` to list files in a single column because you redirect that to `/dev/null` anyway
- the `` `...` `` part will only output anything if there were files, so you don't need `yes == yes`, it's enough to check for emptiness

If you don't mind using Bash instead of Tcsh, then the ifs can be even more simple:

```
if ls DSC*.jpg &> /dev/null; then
```

A lot less useless fluff.

With Bash you could simplify the repetitive blocks with a function, for example:

```
check_files() {
    glob=$1
    flags=$2
    nomsg=$3
    echo Checking "$glob"
    if ls $glob &>/dev/null; then
        jhead -a$flags -ft -autorot -n $glob
    else
        echo $nomsg
    fi
    echo
}

check_files 'DSC*.jpg' nef 'no Nikon jpg files'
check_files 'DSC*.JPG' NEF 'no Nikon JPG files'
check_files 'p*.jpg' rw2 'no Canon jpg files'
check_files 'P*.JPG' RW2 'no Canon JPG files'
```